# как отслеживать любые изменение значения переменной

Tags: java, android

нужно реализовать

```
if(изменилась переменная position){что то происходит}
```

Comment: Лучший вариант - это когда метод, изменяющий переменную и вызывает то что должно происходить

Comment: он меняется динамично и доставляется неограниченно, по этому мне просто нужно знать когда он изменится чтобы обнулить значения

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int positionStart = 0;
int position = positionStart;//position далее меняем по необходимости


if(positionStart != position){
    //что-то делаем
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо человек) я забыл про такой вариант

Answer (score 2):

Посмотри liveData и ViewModel Google

`position.observe(this, Observer { newValue ->  // код }`